# Matplotlib.cbook: Can not import matplotlib.cookbook example csv files

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-16.04

I am running matplotlib version 1.5.1 on python 2.7.1 on ubuntu 16.04.
When I try to get some sample data from matplotlib cbook module, it gives following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/sample_data/msft.csv'
```

The MWE is given below:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
print(matplotlib.__version__)  # 1.5.1
fname = cbook.get_sample_data('msft.csv', asfileobj=False)

with open(fname,'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
```

The example was taken from:
http://nullege.com/codes/search/matplotlib.cbook.get_sample_data

Note: I also looked for bug report.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=691960

However, I could not figure the solution.
So, the question remains is how can we import some sample csv file (or, may be some other png files) from matplotlib.cbook module?

Some links:
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/cbook_api.html
[How to center a plotted image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386151/how-to-center-a-plotted-image)

Comment: Aren't you using anaconda ?

Comment: @yugi, Nope, I am using plain python.

Comment: have you checked if that csv file actually exists there?

Answer (score 0):

use xlrd for csv-files alongside with matplotlib....it works perfectly fine